# Verb for "to become bog/marshland/swamp"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

**Is there a specific verb in English** (perhaps come into the language from the northern Canadian wetlands?) **which would describe the process of an area becoming [bog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bog)** / [marshland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsh) / [swamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp) (combined or separate)?

I tried the Google options for each (a la "[verb for to become swamp](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&hs=3pn&sxsrf=ALeKk015n8mowy-dkNqUKA8UdP79eCLodg%3A1589746911928&ei=35zBXpSROPqEk74PvIG6WA&q=verb%20for%20to%20become%20marsh&oq=verb%20for%20to%20become%20marsh&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAE6BAgAEEc6BggAEBYQHjoICCEQFhAdEB5QwSdYjytgnSxoAHACeACAAYUBiAGDBJIBAzMuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjU_N7f3LvpAhV6wsQBHbyADgsQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)") and didn't get anything which would match.

The opposite, at least when an anthropogenic process and intended, exists, and is ['to drain'](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&hs=Aqn&sxsrf=ALeKk012BQsCzHBUSTu3x2IdGIl06vgnIw%3A1589746918216&ei=5pzBXqjrDKiFmwWVgYTQDg&q=define%20to%20drain&oq=define%20to%20drain&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoCCAA6BAgAEEM6BQgAEMsBOgQIABAKOggIABAWEAoQHlDmgAZYrYwGYLSNBmgAcAF4AIABYYgB_AiSAQIxNZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwio9t7i3LvpAhWowqYKHZUAAeoQ4dUDCAs&uact=5):

- cause the water or other liquid in (something) to run out, leaving it empty or dry.

Edit (Clarifications): I should note -- as the comments already did -- that appreciably, 'bog', 'marsh', and 'swamp' all describe different wetlands. I am most interested in 'bog', but I reasoned that either of the other two processes could also be helpful if described as a verb.

Comment: In English, you can verbify almost every noun. Why not verbify 'marshland'? Why not say 'marshlandise', 'marshlandify' or 'marshlanden'?

Comment: @GEdgar - How about "swamp the drain"?

Comment: Another place to ask, possibly: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com

Comment: How about boggify? Keep in mind that marshlands and swamps are different, and no doubt different in formation.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I'm not sure you can verbify *verb*.

Comment: @RichardKayser, It's already verbified.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: While that's true, in many cases that doesn't sound very good (like in this one).

Comment: @Xanne: Yes, it's a fair point. The processes are different as the words describe different things. Nevertheless, I was hoping there would be at least a word for one of these.

Comment: Does anyone know if any terms entered English from either the First Nations' languages or French in Canada to describe these areas (it's the most likely place I can imagine English-speaking people coming across bogs)?

Comment: "Verbing weirds language" (Calvin and Hobbes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **inundate**? From M-W:

> **[inundate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inundate)**: to cover with a flood, overflow

Synonyms include drown, flood, submerge, submerse, swamp. **Inundate** is more general than flood.

Marshlands, bogs, and swamps are all the result of an area being inundated by water for one reason or another, e.g., tides, seasonal flooding of low-level areas, precipitation, etc.

*To **inundate*** is the opposite of your *to drain*.

Comment: An inundation -- from floods at least -- would be temporal, not permanent. Is there a way to reflect this as well? I've only seen "inundate" thus far with respect to riverine overflows (e.g., Mississippi).

Comment: Same meaning “to swamp” but that dies not convey the  meaning of “becoming a swamp”.

Comment: @gktscrk Marshes, bogs, and swamps are all wetlands, whereas wetlands, as defined by the U.S. EPA, are areas where water covers the soil, or is present either at or near the surface of the soil all year or for varying periods of time. Wetlands can be temporal or permanent, with the water coming from some combination of flooding and rain.

Comment: I think that's a fair point, @RichardKayser. It's not, however, necessarily a word you could use without other descriptors to describe what is going on, but that is indeed the process.

Comment: @Hachi I'm not sure *to swamp* and *to inundate* have exactly the same meaning. I do agree though that *to swamp* does not have the meaning of *becoming a swamp*, whereas *to inundate* does have the meaning of *becoming an inundation*, and inundations can result in wetlands, including swamps.

Comment: @gktscrk It was the best one-word answer I could come up with.